Lookup values to new columns like vlookup
In Power Query, how can I lookup and fill the values "?" which I highlighted in yellow.
I need to fill the columns F G H, based on A&B (or Textjoin column). In short, I need to fill the last three columns in Power Query. Is there a formula like vlookup?


I tried creating a new column with conditions, but it doesn't work.

Merely Select the Type column, and Pivot on that using Sum for the aggregation.


Select the Type column
From the Transform tab, select Pivot
Ensure the dialog box looks like:


Result

